# Any API to get Pirl address balance?

Tags: php

I want to get the balance of a Pirl address using PHP, but I can't seem to find any. I have found `wss://alpha.diver.pirl.io/api/` but I'm not sure how to access it by using PHP?

Answer (score 0):

WSS is a websocket. There's third-party libraries to accomplish connecting to a websocket in PHP, but I decided to just use Javascript. Here's my example of connecting to the PIRL Diver API via a websocket and injecting the wallet balance into the div with the class: ".balance.stats-box". Excuse some formatting issues as I did this in PHP by echoing it inside of the  tags (but you get the idea from the example below).

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        var wsUri = "wss://alpha.diver.pirl.io/api/";

        function init() {
            testWebSocket();
        }

        function initEnd() {
            websocket.close();
        }

        function testWebSocket() {
            websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);
            websocket.onopen = function(evt) { onOpen(evt) };
            websocket.onclose = function(evt) { onClose(evt) };
            websocket.onmessage = function(evt) { onMessage(evt) };
            websocket.onerror = function(evt) { onError(evt) };
        }

        function onOpen(evt) {
            console.log("Connected.");
            doSend(\'{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"getAddressByHash","params":{"hash":"'.$_GET["PIRLWalletAddr"].'"},"id":1}\');
        }

        function onClose(evt) {
            console.log("Finished/Disconnected.");
        }

        function onMessage(evt) {
            var walletVal = JSON.parse(evt.data)["result"]["wal_value"];
            if (walletVal != undefined) {
                $(".balance.stats-box").append(Math.round(walletVal));
                websocket.close();
            }
        }

        function onError(evt) {
            console.log(\'ERROR: \' + evt.data);
        }

        function doSend(message) {
            websocket.send(message);
        }

        init();
    });
</script>

<div class="balance stats-box"></div>
```